# Using boost::function with a parameter to shared pointer to derived class

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, derived-class

Using C++ with g++ 5.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have a class A, and a class B that derives from class A. Function f1 takes a shared pointer to class A as parameter. Function f2 takes a shared pointer to class B as parameter and return the same type as f1. Using boost::function, another function F takes a function such as f1 as parameter. The code looks like this :

```
result_t f1 ( const boost::shared_ptr<A> a );
result_t f2 ( const boost::shared_ptr<B> b );
typedef boost::function < result_t (const boost::shared_ptr<A>&) > f1_t;
void F ( const f1_t f );
```

Calling F with f1 as argument works fine. I now want to call F but with f2 as argument. I get the following error :

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type const boost::shared_ptr<B>& from expression of type const boost::shared_ptr<A>
           return f(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS);
```

There's not really a need for F to get this error, doing :

```
f1_t f = f2;
```

gives the same error.

Comment: So... what's the question? Note that with gcc 5.4.0 you can use `-std=c++11` and `std::function`/`std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I think there's a code smell in the design. You can't call `f2` on a `shared_ptr<A>` unless it actually points to a `B` anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no co-variance for function prototypes. Different signatures are simply that: different types.

In this case you'd need to wrap the function with a converting wrapper.

Let's create a few facility definitions:

```
using result_t = int;
struct A { };
struct B : A { };

typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;

result_t f1(APtr) { return 1; }
result_t f2(BPtr) { return 2; }

typedef boost::function <result_t(APtr const&)> funOfA;
typedef boost::function <result_t(BPtr const&)> funOfB;
```

Now wrapping `funOfB` as a `funOfA` would look like this:

```
funOfA wrapFunOfB(const funOfB f) {
    struct {
        funOfB _f;
        result_t operator()(APtr const& a) const { 
            return _f(boost::static_pointer_cast<B>(a));
        }
    } wrap { f };

    return wrap;
}
```

Now you can easily write:

```
int main() {
    F(f1);
    F(wrapFunOfB(f2));
}
```

### Simple C++03 Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a182181a05d4f092)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef int result_t;
struct A { int i; };
struct B : A { int j; };

typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;

result_t f1(APtr) { return 1; }
result_t f2(BPtr) { return 2; }

typedef boost::function <result_t(APtr const&)> funOfA;
typedef boost::function <result_t(BPtr const&)> funOfB;

struct Wrapper {
    typedef result_t result_type;
    funOfB _f;

    result_t operator()(APtr const& a) { 
        return _f(boost::static_pointer_cast<B>(a));
    }
};

funOfA wrapFunOfB(const funOfB f) {
    Wrapper wrap = { f };
    return wrap;
}

void F(const funOfA f) {
    APtr a = boost::make_shared<A>();
    APtr b = boost::make_shared<B>();

    //std::cout << "f(a): " << f(a) << "\n"; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR if f wraps a funOfB
    std::cout << "f(b): " << f(b) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    F(f1);
    F(wrapFunOfB(f2));
}
```

Prints

```
f(b): 1
f(b): 2
```

### PROBLEMS, WARNINGS: `dynamic_pointer_cast<>`

If `F` actually invokes the parameter on an object that isn't *actually* of type `B`, that `static_cast<>` will invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to protect against that, use `dynamic_pointer_cast`, which requires the classes `A` and `B` to be *polymorphic types*.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7aadc1191ac58391)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef int result_t;
struct A     { int i; virtual ~A() {} };
struct B : A { int j; };

typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;

result_t f1(APtr a) { return a?1 : 0; }
result_t f2(BPtr b) { return b?2 : -99; }

typedef boost::function <result_t(APtr const&)> funOfA;
typedef boost::function <result_t(BPtr const&)> funOfB;

struct Wrapper {
    typedef result_t result_type;
    funOfB _f;

    result_t operator()(APtr const& a) { 
        return _f(boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a));
    }
};

funOfA wrapFunOfB(const funOfB f) {
    Wrapper wrap = { f };
    return wrap;
}

void F(const funOfA f) {
    APtr a = boost::make_shared<A>();
    APtr b = boost::make_shared<B>();

    std::cout << "f(a): " << f(a) << "\n";
    std::cout << "f(b): " << f(b) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    F(f1);
    F(wrapFunOfB(f2));
}
```

Prints

```
f(a): 1
f(b): 1
f(a): -99
f(b): 2
```

### C++11 Version

Things get a little more elegant here. Notably, the Wrapper class can be local, and anonymous:

```
funOfA wrapFunOfB(const funOfB f) {
    struct {
        typedef result_t result_type;
        funOfB _f;

        result_t operator()(APtr const& a) { 
            return _f(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a));
        }
    } wrap { f };
    return wrap;
}
```

Next level: use a lambda instead:

```
funOfA wrapFunOfB(const funOfB f) {
    return [f](APtr const& a) { return f(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a)); };
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0bfd39c3390fe50)</kbd>**

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

typedef int result_t;
struct A     { int i; virtual ~A() {} };
struct B : A { int j; };

typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<B> BPtr;

result_t f1(APtr a) { return a?1 : 0; }
result_t f2(BPtr b) { return b?2 : -99; }

typedef std::function<result_t(APtr const&)> funOfA;
typedef std::function<result_t(BPtr const&)> funOfB;

funOfA wrapFunOfB(const funOfB f) {
    return [f](APtr const& a) { return f(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(a)); };
}

void F(const funOfA f) {
    APtr a = std::make_shared<A>();
    APtr b = std::make_shared<B>();

    std::cout << "f(a): " << f(a) << "\n";
    std::cout << "f(b): " << f(b) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    F(f1);
    F(wrapFunOfB(f2));
}
```

That's 25% code reduction.

Comment: Works like a charm, exactly what I needed. Thank you for providing C++03 version since I am stuck with it and can't use C++11 (for work reasons).